# How to use numpy "allclose" to return an array of common values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to compare two 1D altitude arrays for common values.

However, I don't want to just find EXACT altitudes between them - altitudes that are "close enough" should be counted as well. In my case, altitudes that are within 2 meters of each other should be considered 'equal'.

I have tried using allclose to start:

```
rtol = 2
atol = 2
common_altitudes = np.allclose(altitude_array_1,altitude_array_2,atol,rtol)
```

Which returns "True"

But, I'd like to get an array back that includes all of these common (or within 2 meters) altitudes in one array. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: The relation "is close to" is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), so you'll need to think carefully about how your calculation is defined.  For example, suppose the input is [1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7], and your tolerance is 2.  Then 1 is close to 2.5, and 2.5 is close to 4, 4 is close to 5.5 and 5.5 is close to 7.  But 1 is not close to 4, 2.5 is not close to 7, etc. So what output do you expect from this input?

Comment: See the `ALL` in `allclose`?  That means it checks if ALL values match, returning on True/False.  That should be clear from the docs.  But can you be more explicit about how you are comparing the arrays?  For example, element-wise you could take the difference, then the absolute values, and choose that are small enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtol=0`, for example:

```
>>> a = [10,11,13,15]
>>> b = [11,13,12,13]
>>> c = [10,9,17,11]

>>> np.allclose(a,b,atol=2,rtol=1)
True

>>> np.allclose(a,c,atol=2,rtol=0)
False
```

According to the [`np.allclose` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

> `absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))`

So in your case you would want:

```
absolute(a - b) <= 2
i.e. absolute(a - b) <= (2 + 0 * absolute(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get back an array with the common values you need to filter the values from the original array:

```
a = np.array([10, 11, 13, 15])
b = np.array([10,  9,  9, 11])

common = a[np.isclose(a,b,atol=2,rtol=0)]
# [10 11]
```